# Add an event handler to a my.settings value

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, my.settings

I want to invoke a method every time a value from `My.Settings` is changed. Something like:

```
Private Sub myValue_Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myValue.Changed
    
    (...)
    
End Sub
```

I know that, if I wanted to do it with a variable, I have to make it a class and set the event on it. But I can´t do it with the value from `My.Settings`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments on another answer, you can receive notification of a change in a setting via a `Binding`. Alternatively, you can do essentially what the `Binding` class does yourself, as there's not really all that much to it, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim settingsPropertyDescriptors = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(My.Settings)
    Dim setting1PropertyDescriptor = settingsPropertyDescriptors(NameOf(My.Settings.Setting1))

    setting1PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(My.Settings, AddressOf Settings_Setting1Changed)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Settings.Setting1 = "Hello World"
End Sub

Private Sub Settings_Setting1Changed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine($"{NameOf(My.Settings.Setting1)} changed to ""{My.Settings.Setting1}""")
End Sub
```

This code adds a changed handler to the property via a `PropertyDescriptor`, just as the `Binding` class does.

Answer (score 0):

In a word: no. `My.Settings` doesn't support this on it's own.

What you can do is make your own class that wraps `My.Settings`. As long as you use this new class, and never go to `My.Settings` directly any more, then you can put an event on that class which will do what you need.

However, even here, there's no way to *enforce* the use of the new class, and prevent direct access to `My.Settings`.

Comment: Wow... That sounds too much for my skills, eh eh. I will give it a try though... Google, here I go...

Comment: My.Settings support DataBindings. Handled by a BindingSource, the `CurrentItemChanged` event notifies when the value of a bound Setting changes. -- You could also use a Binding's `Format` event, which is raised when the value of an item of a bound collection needs to be formatted for presentation. Binding My.Settings, the new value of a Setting is formatted each time its value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? [ApplicationSettingsBase.SettingChanging Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.settingchanging?view=netframework-4.8)

```
Partial Friend NotInheritable Class MySettings
    Inherits Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
    Private Sub MySettings_SettingChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Configuration.SettingChangingEventArgs) Handles Me.SettingChanging
        If e.SettingName.Equals(NameOf(My.Settings.Setting1)) Then
            'Do Stuff
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```